# Angularjs - limit user entry to typeahead suggestion only

Tags: angularjs, typeahead.js, typeahead

Is it possible to limit user entry to Typeahead suggestions only. My problem is, that I have a very long list 4000+ entries, so it would kill the load of my page if I use a dropdown or other control that pre-load all the options. Please advise.

Comment: Of course it's possible

Comment: Do you have a proof?